# Batch set version number for .exe and .dll files

Tags: windows, build-automation, versioning

Is there a tool that would allow me to to do something like this: `thetool.exe '1.0.0.1' mydll.dll myexe.exe`?

Basically I would like to automate the process of making my builds and then have a tool automatically set the version numbers for me.

Comment: Scripting!  Python, whatever you like.  It doesn't come inside of the box because the only thing that makes sense is for a programmer to say that there was a breaking change.  Leaving versioning up to tools is a very lossy proposition.  Never worked yet, other than *everything* is incompatible.  That's well supported.

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the answers to this question: [How do I set the version information for an existing .exe, .dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll)

verpatch /va foodll.dll %VERSION% "%FILEDESCR%" "%COMPINFO%" "%PRODINFO%" "%BUILDINFO%"

Available at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/VerPatch.aspx?msg=3207401

With full sources...

Answer (score 0):

The version number is stored in a [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28VS.85%29.aspx) resource (a compiled binary resource) inside the executable. Most IDEs or compilers come with a resource compiler as well (Delphi and C++ Builder include brcc32.exe, for instance).

Unless your IDE allows you to auto-increment a version or build number as part of the build process, you'll end up needing to create the text .RC file for a VERSIONINFO resource and using your resource compiler to compile it and add it to your final executable or dll.

Comment: Thanks I know about the VERSIONINFO resources... however I find them a pain to update for multiple modules with each build.  I was hoping that they would be stored in a consistent location in binaries that would allow other tools to modify them after the binary has already been compiled/linked.