# Is it possible to set the OriginalFilename property for a .Net assembly with Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

My understanding (which may well be faulty) is that it is easy to set the OriginalFilename property for a C++ DLL or EXE by including a VERSIONINFO resource file in the Visual Studio build.

But I can't find any way of setting OriginalFilename for a C# build. It is apparently always set to the name of the output file being built.

I'd really like to be able to specify this if possible. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK, no answers, and now I've found a workaround.

This article here at StackOverflow was very helpful:
[How do I set the version information for an existing .exe, .dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll)

Which led me to this resource manipulation project written in C#:
http://resourcelib.codeplex.com/

So what I'm going to do is to modify the DLLs after they've been built.

Edit (March 2015): This is an old posting, but I can see there is still some interest in it. The "ResourceLib C# File Resource Management Library" open source project has moved since four years ago, and is now here: https://github.com/dblock/resourcelib

Comment: Have you been able to modify the FileInformations using resourceLib?

Comment: @JMat: Yes, this is still working for me. Although I should perhaps mention that I'm still targetting .Net Framework 3.5. Maybe if/when I update to later versions the .dll files will be sufficiently different that it won't work - I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to set it,
-> **right-click on the project or assembly name in visual studio -> select properties -> select Application tab -> change the assembly name as you want**.

[Please refer the link to view property window, in which assembly name option is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2tFV.jpg)

After changing the name compile the project,(to verify the change) right click your compiled DLL file  and select properties and click on '**Details**' tab, in which you can see the '**original filename**' is now changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no.

You can read what it is with `System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.OriginalFilename`, but the value is filled by the `Project / Output Filename` not from any Assembly Attribute.

Running your patch program to change it after a build runs the risk of breaking any digital signature applied during the build.  You may need to build without signing, patch the attributes, then sign it in a separate step.

Comment: "You may need to build without signing, patch the attributes, then sign it in a separate step." Yes, I apply the company's code signing certificate in a later step.