# ".exe" file I built from Visual studio has ".dll" in original filename in Details tab

Tags: c#

So I built my project but its executable has ".dll" in Original Filename metadata.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8eRv.png)
Is there any way to configure what will be put in this field on build? Solutions that requires modifying .exe after build are not allowed in my case so I would be appreciated for any help with that.

I've tried to set some attributes in AssemblyInfo but I`m not sure if I was using right one.

UPD:1/31/2023: It is not about setting the name. It is about setting the extension. In Properties I am able to set only name, but not the extension.

Comment: Right click the project and hit Properties. See if there is anything in there that lets you set the name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set the OriginalFilename property for a .Net assembly with Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024523/is-it-possible-to-set-the-originalfilename-property-for-a-net-assembly-with-vis)

Comment: That's accurate for any project that targets .NET5+, they get built to a .dll.  The .exe file is the host and does not contain any of your code, its job is to get the CLR loaded and initialized.

Comment: Welcome! Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: @HansPassant, could you please share the link to the source where you got this info?

Comment: look at your install files.  You'll see the dll.

Comment: probably delete the file and build it, maybe the metadata is outdated.