# How to specify File Version when building EXE using MSBuild?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-2010

I'm trying to compile an EXE using MSBuild / Delphi 2010, I tried this:

MSBuild.exe /t:Clean;Build /p:config=Release;ExtraDefines="CodeTest" /property:FileVersion=1.0.0.15 "D:\MyProject\MyFile.dproj"

File is built but version isn't set

What's wrong anyway?

Comment: I have a Perl script that runs as a pre-build event and creates a version resource with the desired version.

Comment: I don't think "/property" sets a versioninfo property in MSBUILD. They are used to do things like set Debug or Release. Note that /p and /property are just two forms of the same command.

Comment: Thank you guys, I indeed ended up using verpatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property "FileVersion" is available inside the MSBuild session, but unless you have a Task or Target that uses it somehow, it's not being used for anything. You'll either need to (as DHeffernan says) create a version resource that your code uses or use a post-compile tool to apply the version info to your exe or dll.

This [StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll) lists a number of tools to do the post-compile thing.

Answer (score 2):

Using `VerInfo_Keys` as an MSBuild property has worked for me.
The rest of the assembly properties you want also need to be provided at the same time however.

`msbuild.exe "D:\MyProject\MyFile.dproj" /p:Config=Release /p:VerInfo_Keys="FileVersion=1.2.3.4;ProductVersion=1.2.3.4;LegalCopyright=Copyright © My Company;ProductName=My Product;CompanyName=My Company" /t:Clean;Build`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that `FileVersion` "attribute" is a part of CSV-list of `VerInfo_Keys` property but not a property itself.

So, the solution which is seen to me is:

1. Take `VersInfo_Keys` property (CSV-list)
2. Split it to Key=Value pairs
3. Change value of FileVersion=... pair
4. Join list back to CSV-list.

I've [implemented](https://gist.github.com/57b034e232be07452e9c4b865bc2896a) this with an [MSBuild Inline Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx) (N.B.: .NET Framework 4.0 and above must be used):

1. Put the gist (noticed above) to a `lib\MSBuildTasks\Delphi.VersionInfo.targets` file (git submodule in my case)
2. Add to a Delphi project file (say `delphi-project.dproj`):

   `<Import Project="lib\MSBuildTasks\Delphi.VersionInfo.targets" Condition="$(FileVersion)!='' and Exists('lib\MSBuildTasks\Delphi.VersionInfo.targets')"/>`

    condition "FileVersion is set" is to avoid failure in Delphi as the latter uses .NET 3.5 which does not support inline tasks (so, FileVersion is only set when run with MSBuild).
3. run

   `msbuild delphi-project.dproj /t:build /p:FileVersion=A.B.C.D`

The same I use for Android apps (with Delphi XE7/10 Seattle). Just `VersionName` and `VersionCode` "properties" are used rather than `FileVersion` (N.B. `Import`'s condition is changed appropriately).

`msbuild delphi-project.dproj /t:build /p:VersionName=A.B.C.D`