# IExpress output file version

Tags: iexpress

How can I set custom version of IExpress output file. I found this article http://www.mdgx.com/INF_web/custver.htm and everything except File version is working fine. Whatever I try I can't seem to set custom file version. It looks like IExpress is ignoring FileVersion setting in SED file and always uses the version of wextract.exe. I have a IExpress version 9 installed.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two different file version numbers: the binary version number (stored as `FILEVERSION` in the resource) and the string version (stored in the `StringFileInfo` block as `FileVersion`). It seems that IExpress only changes the string version, not the binary version.

(As usual, MSDN has all the gory details on the [`VERSIONINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058.aspx) resource if you're interested.)

You might have some luck with a version-changing utility. There are several good answers [on this question about changing version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll).

I tried one called [StampVer](http://www.elphin.com/downloads/stampver/) and it seemed to do the trick.