# How to set complete build number in VB6 (Major.Minor.Build.Revision)

Tags: vb6, version-numbering

How to set the complete version number from vb6 (`VPIaccessMaker.vbg`),from **Visual Basic** i can set Major.Minor.Revision as 3.2.2 in that case my exe version will be 3.2.0.2.How to set build number in this case like 3.2.1.2[image].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the vbAdvance add-in which allows the setting of the version build. It is now freeware, but no longer supported. [You can learn more and download it here.](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/)

Comment: Hi Kelly, a Long time ago i was fallen in love with VBCorlib ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the support. I've been trying to carve out some spare time to update VBCorLib a bit, but it's been difficult. I still tinker with it though.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is you can't with native VB6.

Note  that you can do this in VB.NET but not in VB6 - [See this page from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2fx7ff9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for differences between VB6 and VB.NET projects with regard to version numbering.

You could possibly alter the version of the compiled exe- see this question for some suggestions on this:

[How do I set the version information for an existing .exe, .dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll)