# VB6 - output versions "Majorver minorver a zero and RevisionVer" - how can I change that zero?

Tags: vb6, ide, versioning

I've googled this. Searched here for it. Closest I came to the answer is a guy was asking the same question back in 2003 in another forum!

in the MAKE tab of the project properties in the VB6 IDE, you can set the version number of your build. Major Version, Minor Version and Revision. So say you set these three to 8, 6, and 2  - you'd expect to see your exe to have its version set to 8.6.2 - right?

NOPE. What you get is 8.6.0.2 !!
**I want to set that zero** to be 2 - But I have yet to find out what that third place position is called.

Any of you long time VB6 programmers have a solution to this issue?

Comment: You want to set the build number and that can't be done natively. There are third party tools to do this, and it is probably possible using an API call although I've never researched it.Try this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243804/how-to-set-complete-build-number-in-vb6-major-minor-build-revision

Comment: Thank you so much @jac for the lead. Love that add in!  I now have exactly what I want!  Plus a whole bunch of new capabilities I have yet to play with. Love that VBAdvance! [link]http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/

Comment: @MarkJ am I dinged for this "duplicate" ? how do I challenge that?

Comment: @HarryA There's no penalty or anything for submitting a question that's a duplicate; it's just StackOverflow's way of consolidating information to all be in one place. This question now serves as a signpost for others who might use different words to describe the same problem as the original.

Comment: @HarryA What Peter says is exactly right. I marked your question as a duplicate but there's nothing negative intended at all. It doesn't reduce your reputation (looks like you earned 40 points). There are often several different ways of asking questions about essentially the same issue. When that happens, the community keeps one "open" (whichever one was asked first) and closes the others as "duplicates".  The idea is to keep the answers and discussion in one place. We keep the "duplicates" around so that people who find them on Google can get to the main "open" question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @jac I found [VBAdvance](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance/) from the thread he pointed me to. and it does exactly what I want and more.