# How to set the properties of an exe (like Product Name, Product Version etc..,) in eclipse RCP product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Any tool for manipulating the details like

File Description,
 File Version,
 Product Name,
 Product Version,
 Copyright,
 Language etc..,

I want to edit the details of an .exe file to have my own specific information's to be visible.

Comment: What sort of Eclipse RCP application? e4 or 3.x? Using a workspace with the org.eclipse.resources plugin or managing files some other way?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and I'm not using org.eclipse.resources.plugin instead we are managing files the same way java.io package does. We are writing our own plugins for the product.

I just wanna know during exporting product how to set these information in .exe file.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The eclipse.exe files downloaded from eclipse.org don't seem to have this info set so I guess there is no way to do it in the Eclipse build. You will have to use an separate tool.

Comment: I don't do Windows development anymore so I don't know.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll)

Comment: @greg-449: Thanks for your reply, verpatch tool works fine for me.