# MSI wix upgrade - getting FileNotFoundException from time to time

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have a WIX installer running upgrade.

it completes successfully the vast majority of times. but in some cases I'm getting:
"IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly.... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

the actual file not being found is not consistent and changes between errors.

**Note:** I have a WIX installation that wraps several MSIs together. the error I'm getting happens during the upgrade process itself where I run some custom c# code (to configure the machine and the environment). this code is NOT run as a custom action, rather it runs after all the inner MSIs complete (and they complete successfully).

Since the same installer completes successfully almost all the time I'm inclined to think this is an environmental issue but I cannot come up with a plausible theory to even start and test this.

this upgrade process can run on windows server 2008 r2 to the latest windows server.

The installer makes sure all .net framework prerequisites are already installer before proceeding.

Any clue on a possible reason for this to happen will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When diffing the before and after folders, what files do you see missing? Binaries? Config files? Your own files or runtime components? Sometimes files that have been removed accidentally and marked permanent in older setups can make new setups appear to work. I don't think this is your case though.

Comment: edited the question - see that the failure happens during the upgrade process and not in the deployed code.
AFAIK - the installer deploys itself to a temp folder that is cleared after the installation completes so I haven't has a chance to compare the execution folder

Comment: Perhaps copy the installation folder first to the desktop and then diff it with the post-installation state. If there are many MSI setups inside this bundle they could have different bugs among them. What runtimes do you deploy and is the GAC involved?

Answer (score 1):

***Quick Brainstorm***: **`1)`** You could have downgraded files? **`2)`** you have mismatched component GUIDs? **`3)`** you have removed files without realizing? (could work if older setup version had file set permanent) **`4)`** you have missing pre-requisites? **`5)`** custom actions can have deleted files? **`6)`** virus scanners can have quarantined files?

There are edge and fringe cases. Right now I can only think of [transitive conditions for components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/using-transitive-components) (`msidbComponentAttributesTransitive` => component conditions are re-evaluated on reinstall potentially removing the file), but that should not affect major upgrades I think.

---

***Downgraded Binary***: It could be an issue of a downgraded binary. Downgrading a binary in your upgrade setup (including a lower version file to replace a higher version from the original setup) can result in files being missing after the installation. Try to run repair from Add / Remove Programs and launch the application again. If this solves the problem and the application launches you very likely have this problem on your hands. An ugly fix that I have recommended for this is to update the version number of an old binary to a higher version using File => Open as resource in Visual Studio. [There are other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47163330/129130), but I use that approach for pragmatic reasons.

***Logging***: There are several other possibilities. The first thing you should do is to [make a proper log file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130):

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*v C:\Your.log
```

and then look for entries like these:

```
MSI (s) (0C:5C) [16:13:25:890]: Disallowing installation of component: {015A4DC1-56F4-562B-96B5-B3BE0D45FA5F} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
MSI (s) (0C:5C) [16:13:25:890]: Disallowing installation of component: {4B6A1404-3892-5BEF-AB47-8FE3149211A4} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
```

See [this old answer from Rob Mensching himself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15139855/129130). And [here is more from Chris Painter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47163330/129130).

***Logging How-To***: Here is an answer on [MSI logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130). I would just *`enable the global logging policy so all MSI operations create a log file in the TEMP folder`*.

***Mismatched Component GUIDs***: You should keep component GUIDs stable between setups unless you move files to another location (in the source media - in other words install to a different absolute target path). If you sequence the RemoveExistingProducts action to run late your component referencing errors might cause files to be missing after major upgrade as the setup enforces component rules in this scenario (with early sequencing these rules can be bent).

- If you use mismatched component GUIDs - in other words you don't keep the component GUIDs stable for files targeting the same absolute path AND you use late sequencing for the .
- [When should you change component GUIDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405100/change-my-component-guid-in-wix/1422121#1422121) (recommended).

Comment: tnx for the info,  I edited my question to emphasis that the error is happening during the upgrade process itself and not in the deployed code