# Set exe file description and version with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm using [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to convert a Python file to EXE. Everything is working well, but the file attributes that I set in the `setup` command are not visible in the file properties:

```
setup(
    name="myfile",
    options=options,
    version="1.2.3.4",
    description='My file',
    executables=executables
)
```

I expect to see the file description and file version when I right click the generated EXE file and go to Details:

[image: file properties]

As you can see the **File description** and **File version** are empty, although I set them up in the `setup` command.

Any way to have these details show in the file properties **by a Python or cx_Freeze process (not by an external software on the existing EXE file [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll))**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem so I'm gonna answer myself...

Just install `pywin32` and it will show all the info:

[image: file properties]