# How to add author name to created exe file using MATLAB application compiler?

Tags: matlab, executable

I have created a program using MATLAB Application Compiler. But after compiling I can not see author name in exe details. How can I add author name to detail of exe file?

Thanks.[image]

[image]

Comment: Most of us don't speak the language show here (Turkish?), can you let us know what is the author name on the screenshot?

Comment: If it cannot be done directly from matlab deploy tool, have a look at this thread for post-editing exe resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll

Comment: @AnderBiguri There is no line as author name in screenshot

Comment: @CitizenInsane So, why we fill application information? It does not make sense.

Comment: @AhmetGökhanPoyraz Deploy tool uses these information to create the installer of your application (i.e. they will be all displayed during installation of your application). Anyhow they are not used to fill generic "FileVersion, Copyright, etc..." resources inside the .exe. While they could smartly have done it for some of them, others have no equivalent (email, description, etc...). I even think "Version" can be any string in deploy tool but "FileVersion" of .exe must be of the form "x.y.z.w" with number only (so not easy equivalent)