# Verifying the version set on a C++ dll/so

Tags: c++, cmake

I am building a C++ library on Windows and Linux, and would like to verify that the Version is being set correctly. I have added the following to the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
project ("TestProject" VERSION 999.999.999 LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_subdirectory ("TestProject")

set_target_properties("TestProject" PROPERTIES 
                              VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
                            SOVERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR})
```

When I build on Linux, I can see that the version is appended to the end of the `.so` file. But on Windows, all I see is the `.dll` file.

Is there any way for me to validate the version of the `.so` and `.dll` files?

Comment: ***Is there any way for me to validate the version of the .so and .dll files?*** No, I don't believe anything is builtin to do that. Although with that said you can change the naming convention to append the version.

Comment: I'm not sure if `SOVERSION` has any effect for MS Windows DLLs, though someone else may well correct me. If you want a cross-platform way to embed the version of a project into a binary, you can set macro definitions in the CMake file and then use these to populate some global variables in your program/library. I do this for some of my projects, here is a code template: https://github.com/saxbophone/CPP20-Cross-Platform-Template

Comment: About checking version of a `.dll` file, see e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284258/how-do-i-set-the-version-information-for-an-existing-exe-dll). (As noted by previous commenter, version of the `.dll` is not of soversion kind, so SOVERSION property doesn't affect on it.) About checking version of `.so` file, it can be performed with `objdump -p <path/to/file>` or `readelf --dynsym <path/to/file>`, both outputs will contain the `SONAME` entry.