# Mvn command fails when I try to setup a new quickstart project

Tags: maven

I am trying to use below command to download a existing quickstart project using Maven but it throws error.

```
mvn -DarchetypeVersion=5.2.5 -Darchetype.interactive=false -DarchetypeArtifactId=quickstart -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.tapestry -DgroupId=de.laliluna \ -Dpackage=de.laliluna.helloworld -DartifactId=helloworld --batch-mode \ -DarchetypeRepository=http://tapestry.apache.org archetype:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.114 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-26T23:30:40+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/77M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Windows\System32). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject Exception
C:\Windows\System32>
```

Somebody help me here pls ? :)
Edit :
I just noticed the command is three line command. I am new to maven and learning hibernate now. Any help on how to execute below command ?

```
mvn -DarchetypeVersion=5.2.5 -Darchetype.interactive=false -DarchetypeArtifactId=quickstart -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.tapestry -DgroupId=de.laliluna \
-Dpackage=de.laliluna.helloworld -DartifactId=helloworld --batch-mode \
-DarchetypeRepository=http://tapestry.apache.org archetype:generate
```

Comment: Version of maven 3.2.5

Comment: The error says that you're running it in a directory without a POM. You have to run maven in a directory with a POM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably on Windows.  [The character to split commands across multiple lines on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605724/2646526) is `^`, not `\`.  Probably easier to just stick the whole command on one line though:

```
mvn -DarchetypeVersion=5.2.5 -Darchetype.interactive=false -DarchetypeArtifactId=quickstart -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.tapestry -DgroupId=de.laliluna -Dpackage=de.laliluna.helloworld -DartifactId=helloworld --batch-mode -DarchetypeRepository=http://tapestry.apache.org archetype:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is in your code snippet is that there is **no pom.xml file present where you are trying the mvn command** go the folder where pom.xml is present then perform the actions you want to do.

For example

**cd c:\workspace\project** where your pom.xml is then you can apply the commands

**mvn clean,install,package**

Comment: I am not sure but the instructions told me to just run the command to download a quick start project.I have no project or pom