# Can't able to connect Android things Respberry pi 3 to Wifi gives Error: No intent supplied

Tags: android, adb, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I successfully connected to Raspberry pi3 (android things preview image) via following command 
 `adb connect <ip-address>`

but after to connect Wifi  using following command :

```
 adb shell am startservice \
    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
    -a WifiSetupService.Connect \
    -e ssid dsid \
    -e passphrase am@sin305
```

it gives following error msg :

```
 Error: No intent supplied
```

Problem solved already :
By following changes  (Don't comment now) -
Tip : remove all backslash from above command.

now it's connected to Wifi successfully.

Comment: are you on a windows machine?

Comment: I am getting the same error. Have you found the solution to this problem?

Comment: @Blundell, I'm using windows machine.

Comment: @YasirTahir I submitted an answer for windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following command used from android studio terminal window,then only it's work :

```
 adb shell am startservice
    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService
    -a WifiSetupService.Connect
    -e ssid dsid
    -e passphrase am@sin305
```

Tip : remove all backslash from above command.( for Windows OS )

now it's connected to Wifi successfully.

Comment: FWIW, the backslashes are standard macOS/Linux syntax for "this command continues on the next line".

Answer (score 2):

`\` is the linux character for a continuing line command. Since you are on windows you have to use `^` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605686/windows-how-to-specify-multiline-command-on-command-prompt).

Like so:

```
adb shell am startservice ^
    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService ^
    -a WifiSetupService.Connect ^
    -e ssid dsid ^
    -e passphrase am@sin305
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connecting to a 2.4ghz network and not a 5.0 (which android things doesn't seem to support)