# Docker run: multi-line

Tags: windows, docker, command-line

Is there a way of running in windows command prompt, a "docker run" command over multiple lines e.g. instead of

```
"docker run -v .. --name .. --entrypoint .. <image_name>"
```

something like

```
"docker run 
-v. ..
--name ..
--entrypoint ..
<image_name>"
```

It's becoming a pain to edit! Thanks, Jonny

edit: I've tried adding in ^ command, it doesn't work. Just errors with `"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows: How to specify multiline command on command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605686/windows-how-to-specify-multiline-command-on-command-prompt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long commands split over multiple lines in Windows Vista batch (.bat) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-windows-vista-batch-bat-file)

Comment: edited the question, I didn't have much luck with adding ^ in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best tool is docker-compose and it uses docker-compose.yml file to prepare run or build instructions.

So it will be a text file in yml or yaml format and take a reference on different keywords for it's prepartion.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

```
Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications.  
With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services.   
Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration.   
To learn more about all the features of Compose, see the list of features.
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone ended up here instead of the possible duplicates above and is put off by the ^ didn't work for me:
if using dos (i.e. not powershell)
replacing the characters
 \
space and backslash at the end of the docker command for linux with
 ^
i.e. space and caret at the end of all but the penultimate line, seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

docker run -v ^
more? --name ^
more? --entrypoint ^
more? <image_name>

more? is by default asking for further commands in Command Prompt.

In windows, you can use ^ caret sign and \ backslash on mac to run multiple line of commands for docker.