# Error deploy the image processing function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am following the OCR tutorial on Google Cloud website (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr?hl=en_GB#functions-prepare-environment-python), however, I can't deploy the image processing function.This is the command I ran:

```
gcloud functions deploy ocr-extract \
--runtime python39 \
--trigger-bucket YOUR_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME \
--entry-point process_image \
--set-env-vars "^:^GCP_PROJECT=YOUR_GCP_PROJECT_ID:TRANSLATE_TOPIC=YOUR_TRANSLATE_TOPIC_NAME:RESULT_TOPIC=YOUR_RESULT_TOPIC_NAME:TO_LANG=es,en,fr,ja"
```

The errors I get are:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) unrecognized arguments: \

To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS

'--runtime' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'--trigger-bucket' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'--entry-point' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'--set-env-vars' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you executing the command in CMD?

Comment: Yes, I'm running in CMD in python virtual environment in the directory of sample code that is provided by google (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/ocr/app)

Comment: Try the command without the '\' character, for some reason the error message seems to say that your cmd is recognizing '\' as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example provided is linux/unix oriented and it uses the continuation character `\` for issuing multiline commands, but you are very likely running the command in windows.

If that is the case, please, try providing the whole command in a single line or use an equivalent continuation character: [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605686/how-to-write-a-multiline-command) provides several alternatives for using multiline command in different windows versions, in cmd and Powershell, in summary, as pointed out as well by @TimRoberts in his comment, you can use the caret `^` command in cmd or the back tick ` in Powershell.

Comment: For future reference, the equivalent character for command continuation on Windows is the caret `^` .  This is not terribly well-known.

Comment: Thank you very much @TimRoberts. The mentioned SO question indicates that as well, but you are right, it is of great value to provide the information directly in the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! It works when I insert the caret ^ instead of the continuation character \.

Comment: You are welcome @Nina, I am happy to hear that it worked properly.