# while execute "az pipelines run --parameters [KEY]=[VALUE]", how to pass value with multi line string as single parameter

Tags: pipeline

while execute "az pipelines run --parameters [KEY]=[VALUE]", how to pass value with multi line string as single parameter.

az pipelines run --id xxx--detect true --organization %organization%  --project %project% --debug --parameters key=[value]

Comment: Hey! az pipelines is a CLI like any other, this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605686/how-to-write-a-multiline-command should be helpful. You should be able to use the standard windows or linux multiline delimiter. Does this answer your question?