# Need help or suggestions to Run Helm install on command prompt

Tags: kubernetes-helm, chaos

How to run this in command prompt. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```bash
helm install steadybit-agent --namespace steadybit-agent \
    --create-namespace  \
    --set agent.key=xxxxxxxxxx \
    --set cluster.name=ChaosEngSteadybit \
    --set agent.registerUrl=https://platform.steadybit.com \
    --set agent.containerRuntime=containerd \
    steadybit/steadybit-agent
```

Not able to run multiple lines in command prompt at one go.
How to run this in windows command prompt. any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a multiline command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605686/how-to-write-a-multiline-command)

Comment: Could you please share the error?

Answer (score 0):

***CASE I:*** In CMD, Use `^` , example

```
helm install steadybit-agent --namespace steadybit-agent ^
    --create-namespace  ^
    --set agent.key=xxxxxxxxxx ^
    --set cluster.name=ChaosEngSteadybit ^
    --set agent.registerUrl=https://platform.steadybit.com ^
    --set agent.containerRuntime=containerd ^
    steadybit/steadybit-agent
```

***CASE II:***  In PowerShell, Use **`** (backtick)

```
helm install steadybit-agent --namespace steadybit-agent `
    --create-namespace  `
    --set agent.key=xxxxxxxxxx `
    --set cluster.name=ChaosEngSteadybit `
    --set agent.registerUrl=https://platform.steadybit.com `
    --set agent.containerRuntime=containerd `
    steadybit/steadybit-agent
```