# Windows batch file - populate file with custom file names

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, set

I would like to create a Windows batch file "printFileNames.bat" that print custom file names as follows:
`Adobe_1`, `DIFX_2`, `WinRAR_3`...

I cannot figure out how to work with variables in a loop. This is what I have:

```
for /r C:\myDir\ %%i in (*) do (
   set counter=counter+1
   set myFileName=%%i+counter
   echo myFileName >> C:\list.txt
)
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to obtain the required output without using an explicit counter:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=: tokens=1*" %%R IN ('DIR /A-D-H /B /S D:\to_delete\* ^| FINDSTR /N .') DO (
  ECHO %%~dpnS_%%R%%~xS
)
```

The `DIR` command provides the list of files, `FINDSTR` supplies it with numbers, the `FOR /F` loop processes thee output of `FINDSTR` to separate numbers from file names and `ECHO` produces the final output where numbers are appended to the file names.

Note that the numbers get appended to the *names*, i.e. before the extensions, so that a file name like this:

```
D:\path\name.ext
```

changes to something like this:

```
D:\path\name_1.ext
```

If you actually want it to be like this:

```
D:\path\name.ext_1
```

replace the `ECHO` command above with the following:

```
ECHO %%S_%%R
```

Comment: +1: I believe, however, that the OP wanted this: `echo %%~nS_%%R >>list.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Three things to know:

1. If you want to perform variable arithmetic, use the [`set /a`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) command (the documentation is a bit outdated though).
2. If you want to employ `if` statements inside the `for` loop, they will break the loop. You can use [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to call an inner subroutine, and users `if` from there. The parameters in the subroutine are passed through the variables `%1`, `%2`, etc... (just like in an ordinary batch file).
3. Lets assume a full path is stored in `%%f`. If you want to extract just the name without the extension, use the [`%%~nf` form](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

That being said, try the following code:

```
    @echo off
    set counter=0
    for /r "C:\myDir\" %%f in (*) do (
        set /a counter+=1
        call :HandleFile "%%f"
    )
    goto :eof

:HandleFile
    if "%~x1"==".jpg" goto :eof
    if "%~x1"==".gif" goto :eof

    set "myFileName=%~n1_%counter%"
    for %%^" in ("") do >>C:\list.txt echo %%~"%myFileName%
```

**EDIT**: fixed the script to handle special file names and skip files with certain extensions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You cannot use an `if` statement in a `for` loop, because it will break the loop. You'll need to call a subroutine from within the loop, and do your stuff from there. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody. You saved my day.

Comment: @EitanT: Excuse me, but an `if` inside a `for` does _NOT_ break it; you may use any `if` and `for` commands combination nested at any level with no problem at all! What _DOES_ break a `for` command is a `goto`!

Comment: @Aacini you are right, I stand corrected. But the code in my answer is still completely correct...

Comment: @Eitan T - You should use `set "myFileName=%~n1_%counter%"`, else it will fail for filenames with special characters like `Cat&Dog.txt`

Comment: @Eitan T- I missed the obvious, now the `set "...` works but the code will fail in the next line `echo Cat&Dog.txt`. This can be solved with [disappearing quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4645113/463115)  `for %%^" in ("") do echo %%~"%var%`

Comment: @jeb What you've suggested works for a simple `echo` command, but it doesn't work properly when you add the `>>list.txt` to it. It doesn't redirect it to the file.

Comment: @Eitan T - As it's a disappearing quote, you need two of them `for %%^" in ("") do echo %%~"%var%%%~" >> list.txt` or change the order `for %%^" in ("") do >> list.txt echo %%~"%var%`

Comment: +1: @jeb, very elegant, love it. Thanks for the info, everyday I learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

You need delayed expansion to access the value of the counter in your loop.
And for incrementing your counter you need the `SET /A` switch.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set counter=0
for /r C:\myDir\ %%i in (*) do (
  set /a counter=counter+1
  set "myFileName=%%i_!counter!"
  echo !myFileName!>> C:\list.txt
)
```

This would fail if your filenames contains exclamation marks `!`, then you need a more stable version like this one

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set counter=0
for /r C:\myDir\ %%i in (*) do (
  set /a counter=counter+1
  set "filename=%%i"

  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "myFileName=!filename!_!counter!"
  echo !myFileName!>> C:\list.txt
  endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set N=0
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%i in ('dir /b C:\mydir\') do (
    set /a N+=1 
    echo %%i_!N!
)
```

Comment: The approach seems correct, but the OP wants a recursive loop. Why did you change it to a `/f`?

Comment: Yes you are right, I forget this part when I search how to remove the extension from the filename.