# Translate a simple command from bash to batch. Multiple line string

Tags: bash, batch-file, github

This command works on linux

I can't get it to work on windows. There is an obvious problem with the string over multiple lines. I have already tried with appending ^ to each line. Didn't seem to work

I have also already looked at [Splitting Doublequoted Line Into Multiple Lines in Windows Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643376/splitting-doublequoted-line-into-multiple-lines-in-windows-batch)

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "your@email.to.match" ]
then
    cn="Your New Committer Name"
    cm="Your New Committer Email"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "your@email.to.match" ]
then
    an="Your New Author Name"
    am="Your New Author Email"
fi

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
'
```

Otherwise -- I would appreciate another way of changing author/committer on github

Any help is appreciated -- Thank you!

Comment: Have the script from this link
https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info

Comment: If you have solved your issue yourself, please post and self-accept your answer *or*, in the worst case, delete the question.

Comment: I couldn't at that time. I can now. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed Cygwin.

Then it ran like a charm