# How to echo symbols like "&" in a batch command processor?

Tags: batch-file

This is my first text based game and I have almost no experience in coding. I've recently run into a problem where I try to echo a "%" but it won't appear in the command processor. Here are some lines of the code:

```
echo 10. If an icosahedron die has 20 faces, what is the probability of rolling a number with 1 in its digits?
echo A) 40%
echo B) 70%
echo C) 55%
echo D) 95%
```

But when I run it on the processor, the "%" does not display. Next I've tried this:

```
echo A) 40^%^
```

But it does not work. So I searched and tried this:

```
echo A) 40"%"
```

But it does not work as well. Do you know anything that can help?

Comment: To specify a literal percent sign as a string, double it.  Also, depending on whether your `echo` statements exist within a parenthetical code block, you might need to caret escape the `)` symbol.  `echo A^) 40%%`

Comment: Thanks guys. It actually helped. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch: Auto escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801769/batch-auto-escape-special-characters) or of [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)

Answer (score -1):

The characters `&`, `%`, `^`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>` and `|` are not usually printable by batch with the `echo` command.
This can be bypassed with the escape character `^`.

```
echo A^) 65^%
echo B^) 70^%
echo C^) 55^%
echo D^) 95^%
```

outputs the desired result.

`%%` also evaluates to `%` as an alternative to `^%`.

Comment: Rubbish. Your claim is false.

Comment: Please explain why

Comment: Had you tested it, you'd have found that the result of running your code is `A) 65echo B) 70echo C) 55echo D) 95` all on one line, plus the next physical line, literally - not what you claim.

Comment: I _did_ test my code. I think that you are running the code in a terminal emulator or within perenthicies `()`.