# New line in clear case format string

Tags: clearcase

So I want to display the versions of an activity:
In the fmt_ccase I found the following format string:

```
%[versions]QCp
```

This returns me the quoted and comma separated version string. But I want then to be split by a newline. I tried the following:

```
cleartool lsact -fmt "%[versions]\np" my_act@\test_pvob
```

And:

```
cleartool lsact -fmt "%[versions]p\n" my_act@\test_pvob
```

Both did not work.
Obviously I could achieve this using Powershell:

```
cleartool lsact -fmt "%[versions]p" my_act@\test_pvob).Split(" ")
```

But I want to now whether there is a ClearCase way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fmt_case documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) only references `[p]Q`, or `[p]C` as separators (quotes, comma), with newlines being '`\n`'.

If it does not work, you would  have to so it by script, either Powershell as you mention, or using a [bat script to process the output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4643376/6309).

The `\n` newline syntax applies to each returned value, and in the case of `%[version]p`, there is only one returned value: the *all* list of versions (space-separated).
So no newline between each versions.

Comment: What just wonders me is that it works for other commands e.g. `ct lscheckout -recurse -fmt "%[aliases]p\n" .\test_vob\` returns me the paths separated by new line

Comment: @andymeissner Right. I just tested `%[versions]pn`: can you test it?

Comment: cleartool lsact -fmt "%[versions]pn" evil_twin_act_1@\test_pvob

Comment: I don't know whether I'm doing something wrong or whether this is inconsistent design

Comment: @andymeissner No, I think the "`]p`": "`Property value: Displays the value of the property specified in square brackets. If multiple values are returned, they are separated by spaces.`" Means that there is no possible separator (like newlines)

Comment: @andymeissner I have edited the answer to explain the apparent design inconsistency.