# In MS DOS copying several files to one file

Tags: dos

I am trying to take a folder that has several .csv files in it and combine all of these files and the information in them, into one file using MS DOS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
copy *.csv new.csv
```

No need for /b as csv isn't a binary file type.

Comment: how do you undo this?  See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357481/undo-a-botched-command-prompt-copy-which-concatenated-all-of-my-files

Comment: Note. This does not work in powershell so make sure you're using cmd. Works perfectly using classic command prompt!

Comment: The command is the right answer expected that i recommend using /B switch. Without that switch an extrat byte 0x1A is added at the end of the resulting file. No matter the csv files, it tells copy to perform a binary copy which avoid any alteration during the copy.

Answer (score 26):

```
copy /b file1 + file2 + file3 newfile
```

Each source file must be added to the copy command with a `+`, and the last filename listed will be where the concatenated data is copied to.

Comment: there isnt a copy all (*) command? BC i have like 30 to 40 files.

Comment: This version lets you specify the exact order in which you'd like the files copied. with the *.csv method above, you'll get the files in random-ish order.

Answer (score 5):

If this is part of a batch script (`.bat` file) and you have a large list of files, you can use a multi-line `^`, and optional `/Y` flag to suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

```vb
REM Concatenate several files to one
COPY /Y ^
    this_is_file_1.csv + ^
    this_is_file_2.csv + ^
    this_is_file_3.csv + ^
    this_is_file_4.csv + ^
    this_is_file_5.csv + ^
    this_is_file_6.csv + ^
    this_is_file_7.csv + ^
    this_is_file_8.csv + ^
    this_is_file_9.csv ^
        output_file.csv
```

This is tidier than performing the command on one line.

Comment: This format is much cleaner. And I can easily format and prepare thousands of file names in VS Code. Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't work in DOS (as this question is tagged) because DOS doesn't support `^` as an escape character

Comment: @phuclv, windows batch does use ^ for splitting lines in batch scripts, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/split-long-commands-in-multiple-lines-through-windows-batch-file

Comment: @default_avatar of course I know that, which is why I commented as above. And it's **not** the character for splitting lines but the [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Windows_Command_Prompt) in Windows cmd. This question is tagged MS DOS so this doesn't apply. DOS doesn't have any escape character and commands must be in a single line

Answer (score 4):

```
type data1.csv > combined.csv
type data2.csv >> combined.csv
type data3.csv >> combined.csv
type data4.csv >> combined.csv
```

etc.

Assume that your using files without headers and all files have the same columns.

Answer (score 4):

filenames must sort correctly to combine correctly!

`file1.bin file2.bin ... file10.bin` wont work properly

`file01.bin file02.bin ... file10.bin` **will** work properly

```
c:>for %i in (file*.bin) do type %i >> onebinary.bin
```

Works for ascii or binary files.

Comment: This worked for me with double quotes.

    for %i in (*.csv) do type "%i" >> onefile.csv

Answer (score 1):

```
for %f in (filenamewildcard0, filenamewildcard1, ...) do echo %f >> newtargetfilename_with_path
```

Same idea as Mike T; might work better under MessyDog's 127 character command line limit

Answer (score -3):

make sure you have mapped the y: drive, or copy all the files to local dir c:/local

c:/local> copy *.* c:/newfile.txt

Comment: @AnnaLear The same mysterious `y` drive... where it's something strange... in the neighbourhood.  Who you gonna call? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMPcuZZgmtE