# rbind of list of selected point txt files

Tags: python, r

I have lot of Point files in a folder. I would like to rbind (Vertically One after another in a single txt file) as per the list of selected point file from all the point files present in the folder.

[rbind of list of selected point txt files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6xqq1rjylo1u5l/rbind%20of%20list%20of%20selected%20point%20txt%20files.zip?dl=0)

**Several Point files in a folder**

[image: Several Point files in a folder]

**list of selected point file in a CSV file**

[image: List of Selected point file]

The output will be a single CSV file consist of all the XYZ of the selected point files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple for loop in R.

```
 setwd("D:/TEST")
    ( p <- list.files(getwd(), pattern="pts$") )
      ptdf <- read.table(p[1], header=FALSE)
        names(ptdf) <- c("x","y","z") 
          for(i in 2:length(p)) {
            d <- read.table(p[i], header=FALSE)
              names(d) <- c("x","y","z") 
            ptdf <- rbind(ptdf, d) 
           }
       write.csv(ptdf, "FileName.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

The "p" vector is defining the files that you will iterate through. You can subset this vector or read in an external file that defines which files will be combined. Here are examples of this.

```
# Create a wildcard list of files in directory and then subset
p <- list.files(getwd(), pattern="pts$")
  ( p <- p[c(1,5,8)] )

# Read on disk file and create "p" vector
# File format is such (one record per line):
#   BP_005424.pts
#   BP_005701.pts
#   BP_005503.pts
p <- read.table("DataList.txt")
  ( p <- as.character(p[,1]) )
```

You can even write out a point shapefile, if so desired.

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)

coordinates(ptdf) <- ~x+y
  writeOGR(ptdf, getwd(), "OutShape", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: After a for loop I am getting an error "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names"

Comment: One more thing I would like to add that I just want to rbind the selected .pts files. which is provided in another CSV file in the same folder. How the code will going to get affected?

Comment: This error is because the names in you files do not match. I changed the code to account for this but beware it does not check to see if your names are in the correct order. That is if one file is x,y,z and the next is y,x,z then you will end up with a miss-assigned column. Your second inquiry is a different question. This is actually quite simple and has to do with specifying the p vector. Just read in the file and assign the desired filenames to p.

Comment: One more query When i opened  the Filename.csv, it shows inverted commas in beginning of each row and end of the row. How to get rid of inverted commas from each row?

Comment: Not working at my end. I have attached link for the files. Its not that heavy. I have created a sample for you. Can you please update your code as per the files in the link. I am not able to understand if i am assigning all the files from a working directory to P then how come i assign the same variable for selected files to P? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Your point data is not csv (comma separated), but rather space delimited, and was an important detail to omit. You will need to change the "read.csv" function in the provided code to "scan". Please do not treat the forum as a code writing service!

Comment: Jeff I am not thinking this platform as a code writing service. But i am learning R with live example files which i came across  few years ago and try to understand each and every line.I can also deal with matrix in several forms in R but dealing with point files and geospatial environment in R is a learning experience for me. thank you for your help though!!

Comment: You may benefit from some of the R tutorials I have on my website (http://evansmurphy.wix.com/evansspatial). I will be adding a number of additional tutorials and tools soon.

Comment: Thank you Evan It did work!!....Thank you again for sharing your website.It gonna really help me out. I will follow your website regularly.One last thing if you get some time then can you please take a look at (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120416/breakline-format-for-arcgis)

Comment: One more thing Jeff, it would be good if you put data.csv file link for every tutorial. The user can play with the data file to try out the codes suggested on your website. That is just my suggestion Jeff!!

Answer (score 1):

If your pts files are simple text files with exactly the same structure then you can make use of the MSDOS command Copy to concatenate the files into a single file. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764558/in-ms-dos-copying-several-files-to-one-file).