# Undo a botched command prompt copy which concatenated all of my files

Tags: windows, command-line, copy, backup, command-prompt

In a Windows 8 Command Prompt, I had a backup drive plugged in and I navigated to my User directory.  I executed the command:
`copy Documents G:/Seagate_backup/Documents`

What I assumed was that `copy` would create the Documents directory on my backup drive and then copy the contents of the C: Documents directory into it.  That is not what happened!

I proceeded to wipe my hard-drive and re-install the operating system, thinking I had backed up the important files, only to find out that `copy` seemingly concatenated all the C: Documents files of different types (.doc, .pdf, .txt, etc) into one file called "Documents."  This file is of course unreadable but opening it in Notepad reveals what happened.  I can see some of my documents which were plain text throughout the massively long file.

How do I undo this!!?  It's terrible because I was actually helping a friend and was so sure of myself but now this has happened.  The only thing I can think of doing is searching for some common separator amongst the concatenated files and write some sort of script to split the file back apart.  But then I would have to guess the extensions of each of the pieces...

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html: "To combine files, specify a single file for the destination, but multiple files as the source. To specify more than one file use wildcards or list the files with a + in between each (file1+file2+file3)
When copying multiple files in this way the first file must exist or else the copy will fail, a workaround for this is COPY null + file1 + file2 dest1"  

Okay great, now if only I could figure out how to undo it....

Answer (score 2):

Merging files together in the fashion that copy uses, discards important file system information such as file size and file name. While the file name may not be as important the size is. Both parameters are used by the OS to discriminate files.

This problem might sound familiar if you have damaged your file allocation table before and all files disappeared. In both cases, you will end up with a binary blob (be it an actual disk or something like your file which might resemble a disk image) that lacks any size and filename information.

Fortunately, this is where a lot of file system recovery tools can help. They are specialized in matching patterns. Specifically they are looking for giveaway clues to what type a file is of, where it starts and what it's size is.
This is for instance enabled by many file types having a set of magic numbers that are used to allow a program to check if a file really is of the type that the extension claims to be.

In principle it is possible to undo this process more or less well.
You will need to use data recovery tools or other analysis tools like binwalk to extract the concatenated binary blob. Essentially the same tools that are used to recover deleted files should be able to extract your documents again. Without any filename of course. I recommend renaming the file to a disk image (.img) and either mounting it from within the operating system as a virtual harddisk (don't worry that it has no file system - it should show up as an unformatted drive) or directly using a data recovery tool or analysis tool which can read binary files (binwalk, for instance, can do that directly, but may not find all types of files as it's mainly for unpacking firmware images that may be assembled in the same or a similar way to how your files ended up).

Comment: This is an old question. Nobody cares about it anymore. Sometimes, Stack Overflow promotes old content to the homepage. This leads to well meaning users like you being duped into wasting their time. If you hate this as much as I do complain on Meta. There are threads about this.

Comment: I care about it still.

Comment: @papiro, Since you still care about a solution, I would suggest taking the resulting file and renaming it to a .img extension and then using a utility to mount the image as a virtual harddisk. Then use a tool like Recurva to recover data from said image file. In principle your concatenated files almost form a simple, but corrupted filesystem on their own (which misses the file allocation table, but has stored files in a contignous fashion). This should be close enough for many recovery utilites in deep scan mode to get back most if not all files.

Comment: @usr, I can understand your side. In fact, I was looking for the syntax of merging files myself (the opposite of what papiro wanted to do), when I stumbled over this question. Having lost files myself in the past, I actually expected papiro to have kept his file until he eventually found a solution, even if the solution was a bit late.

Comment: OK, if he still needs it: My approach would be to use the Wikipedia list of known file prefixes. Then, write a program that splits the file based on those known prefixes. This will recover many files.