# Chrome remote debugging doesn't work with IP

Tags: google-chrome, remote-debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to remote debugg a chrome instance using the remote debug option in chrome:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=1337
```

as described on google page: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/remote-debugging.html

the problem is when i try to access it using IP it doesn't work, while testing it with localhost:1337 does work.

any idea?

Comment: is the port open on windows? when not you have to add to the a windows firewall rules for this port!

Comment: http://www.webkit.org/blog/1620/webkit-remote-debugging/

Answer (score 36):

You can setup an SSH tunnel in order to debug remotely. On the source machine execute:

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9223:localhost:9222 localhost -N
```

Then on the other machine point **Chrome** browser to http://source-machine-ip:**9223**

Comment: Thank you! That one worked out for me just fine. I never managed to use netcat for that.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed, a second time (referenced in Aug 15), to get two GNU/Linux boxes chatting for remote debugging.

Comment: You can also use `-R` flag for remote port forwarding

Comment: Its not working in latest version. Chrome is returning empty response.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar: returning HTTP 200 OK, means it is working. However newer chrome devtools is listening on ws:// instead of http://

Answer (score 21):

The following worked for me when running a Chrome remote debugging host on Windows 8.

1. Add an Inbound Rule to Windows Firewall

   - Search for "Windows Firewall" and select the "Windows Firewall" result
   - On the left of the "Windows Firewall" control panel window, click "Advanced Settings". This will open up "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security".
   - In the tree view on the left, click "Inbound Rules"
   - On the far right, click "New Rule..."
   - Select "Port" (Click Next)
   - Select TCP and set "Specific local ports" to `9222` (Click Next)
   - Select "Allow the connection" (Click Next)
   - Choose the profile access (Domain, Private, Public) to suit your needs (Click Next)
   - Give it a name like `Chrome Remote Debugging (9222)` (Click Finish)
2. Follow [user3445047's instructions on port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22552593/619602):

Run Chrome on the Windows host:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Set up port forwarding on the Windows host:

Open up a `cmd` window. You must "Run as administrator".

Enter the following into the cmd window:

```
netsh
interface
portproxy
add v4tov4 listenport=9222 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

On the client, navigate to `http://THE_HOST_IP_ADDRESS:9222` and you should be presented with a list of "Inspectable Pages".

Answer (score 20):

I don't think Chrome accepts connections from outside of localhost (for security reasons).
I would suggest you have to build small proxy on the same host where Chrome is.

Comment: because they created for mobile devices that you can debug from your desktop and not from a smartphone

Comment: What resource would be recommended to create a proxy? I imagine for most cases this is more trouble than it's worth, but I've thought this several times in the last couple of months.

Comment: Sorry, Chris, I have no recommendation here. I wrote Java from scratch for myself and you probably could also. I know that some flavor of 'nc' (netcat) utility already support proxying (not openbsd).

Comment: I could recommend Charles Web Debugging Proxy.

Comment: Solved: See my answer for complete solution on Windows without installing any third party software.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way of sharing your debugging session with another computer is with [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).
For example, if you've enabled the remote debugging protocol on port 1337 using

```
chromium --remote-debugging-port=1337
```

Then, you can create a tunnel using socat,

```
socat tcp-listen:5656,fork tcp:localhost:1337
```

After doing this, anyone can just visit `http://<YOUR_IP_OR_HOSTNAME>:5656/` and immediately use the debugger.

When you're done, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to terminate socat and thus stop the tunneling.
If the previous code does not work, check whether the firewall (e.g. `iptables`) is blocking access. If the firewall is OK, check whether the IP address or host name is actually correct. To see whether the traffic is correctly forwarded/tunnelled, visit `http://localhost:5656/` and verify that there's a Webkit debugger instance running.

Comment: I get `Host header is specified and is not an IP address or localhost` when trying to access it with another hostname than `localhost`

Comment: If your server is both accessible with IPV6 and IPV4, i would recommand using IP instead of hostname. (Didn't work for me at first since socat was running on IPV4, and chrome was trying IPV6)

Answer (score 10):

1. Start the headless server

   ```
   chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
   ```
2. Set up Port forwarding on windows

   ```
   netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4^
       listenport=9222 listenaddress=0.0.0.0^
       connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=9222
   ```

Comment: On Windows, this in conjunction with adding an Inbound Rule to Windows Firewall works well without the need to install any extra port forwarding utils. See my answer for complete instructions...

Comment: Note that the [line continuation character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079/712526) is (`^`) for `cmd.exe` (as I've added above), but is  backtick (`\``) for PowerShell, instead.

Comment: Chome gives an error if you try this:
`Host header is specified and is not an IP address or localhost.`

Answer (score 8):

recent Chrome versions support the commandline switch "--remote-debugging-address"  so the workarounds listed above should no longer be necessary.

Here the description:
"*Use the given address instead of the default loopback for accepting remote debugging connections. Should be used together with --remote-debugging-port. Note that the re-mote debugging protocol does not perform any authentica-tion, so exposing it too widely can be a security risk.*"

Comment: Do you know how to use this? I've tried all sorts of things and I cannot access the debug tools remotely. Is it asking for the remote clients IP? Or is it asking for a DNS name that will resolve to my machine?

Comment: @Sean256 did you figure this out? No matter what incantation I use I can't make this work..

Comment: @MarcusStade I have not. I have since resorted to creating an ssh tunnel. It must be broken.

Comment: I'm running Chrome under Docker container and adding --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 to the command line allowed me to connect from outside. Easy way to test is to check the version page: http://localhost:9222/json/version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538197/chrome-remote-debugging-from-another-machine States that this only works in headless mode.

Comment: Yes --headless binds the port to the specified IP, but it still looks broke, devtools only partially loads and then halts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple TCP proxy with netcat:

```sh
EXTERNAL_PORT=1338
CHROME_DEBUG_PORT=1337 # This is the port specified with --remote-debugging-port

nc -l -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT} -c "nc 127.0.0.1 ${CHROME_DEBUG_PORT}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing port number
That works for me.