# Remote debugging - how to create a port proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-debugging, google-chrome-devtools, iptables, portforwarding

I'm trying to access remote debugging port running on box A (Debian) from box B (Windows). On box A I'm running Chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=9222` flag and I can see that it works correctly (I can access `localhost:9222` from another browser on A). Also, I'm sure that boxes A and B are connected because I can access `:80` (apache) running on box A from box B just fine. Thing I need to do now is to allow box B access `:9222` on box A. I've done research on port forwarding and iptables rules but I failed to make it work.

**EDIT**

Machine B is Windows so I'm not sure how to use ssh there, I found an [app](http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php) for port-forwarding that seems to work fine. It gives me an error though: "received a connection but can't connect to host-B:9222". So it looks like 9222 is not open for outside connections. Output from netstat on A gives me:

```
root@template:/home/developer# netstat -nap | grep 9222
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9222      0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      24300/user
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269355/1143495). Everything comes down to this:

- open Chrome in one console: `google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`
- and set up a proxy in another one: `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9223:localhost:9222 localhost -N`
- now you should be able to access remote debugging from another machine via `http://192.168.1.123:9223/`

Answer (score 3):

The browser binds socket to localhost address. That is why you have the problem with accessing to the port.

You can solve the problem with help of ssh port forwarding feature.

ssh user@host-A.example.org -L 9111:127.0.0.1:9222

After running this command please open localhost:9111 on host B

ssh will forward the connection to host A and connect it to localhost:9222

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I made port forwarding running on B but it looks like port 9222 is not open for outside word on A. I've edited my question to include additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to forward another port on the host A with help of nc

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat

Comment: Thanks again, clue about netcat was great. It allowed me to find this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9269355/1143495 .