# Using Chromium Remote Debugging from External Device

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, remote-debugging, remote-access, chromium

Chrome can be run to support [remote debugging](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html) by starting it via the command line with a prompt such as `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=C:/foo`. This is often used [to debug on android or iOs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) using a Browser on a Desktop Device but I would like to debug chrome running on a desktop PC. from a "client browser" on the same machine one can call localhost:9222 and see the server browser, calling localhost:9222/json will result in a json representation of the tabs open in the "server browser". This works just fine.

However, when I try to use another device in the same (wifi) network by calling [local IP]:9222 or [local IP]:9222/json (local IP is the IP of the server browser) I get a connection timeout. Is it possible to use remote debugging in such way? Are any other switches needed when starting the browser?

**Edit** I have found some use of forward tcp for the debugging of mobile devices, but there does [not seem to be such a switch for chrome](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

**Edit 2** This seems to be a bit of a duplicate of the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087762/remote-debugging-how-to-create-a-port-proxy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827310/chrome-remote-debugging-doesnt-work-with-ip/9269355#9269355) however, as of yet I have not gotten the solutions presented there to work.

So, apparently this comes down to forwarding a port to localhost:9222. However, at least on windows machines I have no luck with SSH tunnels. Are there any other ways to forward on the machine?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you've mentioned it, the solution is to forward the port **9222**. Below you find approaches for Linux and Windows.

## Linux

After having started chrome with

```
chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Forward the port

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9223:localhost:9222 localhost -N
```

This way you can access the debuggin interface from an external device on port **9223** using a **Chrome** browser.

## Windows

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22552593/209427), on windows (tested on 7,8) the easiest way to do portforwarding without 3rd party apps is via `netsh`

I've created a batch file with the following content. It has to be ran as administrator, and with no previous chrome windows open:

```
netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=9222 listenaddress=0.0.0.0
start /b cmd /c call "\program files\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe" -remote-debugging-port=9222
timeout 5
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9222 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=9222 listenaddress=0.0.0.0
```

This way you can access the debuggin interface from an external device on port **9222**.

Make also sure that no firewall is blocking the corresponding port.

Comment: On Linux, after ssh command, I got ```channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused``` on console side & ```site not found``` on remote browser

Comment: How did you start start chrome with 9222?

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve the same behaviour by adding the argument
`--remote-debugging-address=[YOUR_EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS]` as reported [here](https://codereview.chromium.org/1920773003/), without any additional software other than Chrome itself.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer now. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Its working!
Another important thing to mention is that if you get blank console page, you probably should allow insecure content on site settings of chrome (click on the small lock icon on the address bar)
source -
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging/remote_debugger

Comment: Did not work for me in chrome nor chromium (while trying to get around the google-chrome doesn't work over X since version 77) Unbunti 18.04

Comment: `remote-debugging-address` only works for the headless mode. Very unfortunate, because the only reason I want to use this feature is to see what tests do on my local machine.

Comment: Set it to --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 to remote access from another computer on same local netword

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully used RInetD for easy port-forwarding in Windows 7, tried this and it worked like a charm, externally debugging a Chrome browser in Windows from a Chrome in Mac/Ubuntu.

You can download rinetd from:

http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/

Unzip the file, create an empty file with any name (I used rinetd.conf), with this content:

> 0.0.0.0 9223 127.0.0.1 9222

The in Windows console run it with:

> rinetd.exe -c rinetd.conf

And voila!