# Running Chrome Dev Tools on different computer?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I run two desktop machines (m/kb using Input Director, etc). I would like to run Chrome's dev tools on my second desktop, yet run Chrome on my primary.

I know that Chrome offers remote dev tools for Android, but I am unaware (and unable to find) of any way to do this across PC's.

Is there a way to run Chrome dev tools remotely on PC?

Answer (score 3):

That is actually quite easy.

#### Step 1 :

Make sure to launch the Chrome instance hosting the page you want to inspect (in your case the primary host) with the following additional parameter :

```
 --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

#### Step 2 :

If the Chrome instance where you would like to have your Developer Tools front-end was on the same machine, you would then just have to visit the following url to get a list of the inspectable page :

```
http://localhost:9222
```

Though, as you want to run the front-end on a different computer, you should target your primary hostname or ip. But because remote debugging works only in a context of local instances (thanks Rob W for pointing this out) you have to, for example, make a tunnel between the port 9222 on your primary computer and another port local to the latter. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827310/chrome-remote-debugging-doesnt-work-with-ip).

Comment: `localhost` is usually different on every computer, even if they're on the same network.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've done my test with two Chrome instances on the same machine and messed up a little. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Your updated answer does not work either, because remote debugging is only locally available.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827310/chrome-remote-debugging-doesnt-work-with-ip

Comment: For IPv4, `localhost` should always mean `127.0.0.1` which is the local loopback device. By contrast, the "local IP address" should always be different for each computer on a network, but those are very different things. Chrome only binds the listener to `127.0.0.1` which is only accessible on that device itself.