# VSCode debugger can not connect to puppeteer instance run by Karma

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, puppeteer

I have Angular frontend tests run with Karma and Jasmine that I want to debug with Visual Studio Code. The tests are run in a puppeteer instance.

- When the debugger tries to connect, it times out, and tells me the socket hung up.
- When I visit http://localhost:9333/ where my puppeteer instance is listening I get an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.
- Connecting the debugger to a headless Chrome instance started with `chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9333` works fine.

My karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx'],
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev',
    },
    reporters:
      config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
        ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
        : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        debug: true,
        flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--remote-debugging-port=9333'],
      },
    },
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 120000,
    singleRun: false,
  });
};
```

The relevant part of my launch.json:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Debug Frontend Tests",
  "address": "localhost",
  "port": 9333,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client/web",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL,DR**: Add the flag `'--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0'` to your `customLaunchers`' `flags` array.

It turns out that adding the `'--remote-debugging-port=9333'` flag opens the port only for clients on the local machine. Since puppeteer runs in a Docker container, it views VSCode as a remote client and denies connection.

Running `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` inside the container reveals that Chrome opens the port 9333 only for local clients:

```
root@b6ff203497dc:~# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN 
node    247 root   21u  IPv4 224919      0t0  TCP *:9876 (LISTEN)
chrome  260 root  137u  IPv4 229390      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9333 (LISTEN)
```

Additionally adding the flag `'--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0'` makes Chrome open the port for all IP addresses.

```
root@b6ff203497dc:~# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN 
node    247 root   21u  IPv4 224919      0t0  TCP *:9876 (LISTEN)
chrome  260 root  137u  IPv4 229390      0t0  TCP *:9333 (LISTEN)
```

Now VSCode can connect.

The crucial hints were given by:

[Chrome remote debugging from another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538197/chrome-remote-debugging-from-another-machine)

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5063#issuecomment-561595885