# Selenium How to sendKeys on "could not found find on the page"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm coding a selenium driver program have auto login but I cant find anything on login form.

How to input text in password and account on this form?

[Blank form need to input text](http://ra2-nwp.kishou.go.jp/cityfc/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not HTML form. It's a dialog supplied by OS, not browser. So you can't use selenium to automate it.

You can use Java Class `Robot` to operate it, but `Robot` class can only operate dialog on local where your script reside.  If you use RemoteWebDriver and open browser on remote machine, the `Robot` class will can't work.

So far as I know, there is no good solution to support local and remote cases same time.

Comment: I will be trying view Robot package. Do you give me any technical or library or even any language that can auto-login this form?

Comment: Hope this post can help you as beginning: https://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html

Comment: I tried use Robot but It does not work. Selenium wait to load page for unlimited so it cant run next code. I tried create new Thread for input Robot, auto press function run but nothing input on form

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about basic-auth and there are some solutions.

[Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url/48694496#48694496)

Either via credentials in url(which doesnt work for chrome anymore) or remote-debugging in chrome.

[Chrome remote debugging in a seleniumgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585187/chrome-remote-debugging-in-a-seleniumgrid)

Comment: Can you help me run auto program on localhost (single machine) first?

Comment: the easiest thing you can do is using chrome version <59, e.g. 58 and url credentials "http://user:pass@url". if not you need to connect via webservice to the chrome debugger: https://medium.com/@sahajamit/selenium-chrome-dev-tools-makes-a-perfect-browser-automation-recipe-c35c7f6a2360

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException; 
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username" + Keys.TAB + "password"); 
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

If ur using selenium with java try this

```html
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException; 
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username" + Keys.TAB + "password"); 
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: Please give me package library for there function

Comment: I cant find SetAuthenticationCredentials() function on selenium for Java