# Chrome remote debugging not working (computer to computer)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to make the chrome devtools remote debugging feature work (computer to computer).

A month ago it worked on the same setup that I have, but now, with the same configurations (as far as I can remember), it is not working.

This is how the setup looks like:

Remote machine to debug:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

browse to a page and open devools (F12).

Also activate [port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22552593/4360433) in cmd as administrator:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4^
    listenport=9222 listenaddress=0.0.0.0^
    connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=9222
```

To make sure, I deactivated the firewall.

On the local machine, I go to:

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

and add the other machine ip:9222 in the "Discover network targets". After a few seconds I can see the machine ip appear as a "Remote Target", but its list is empty

[image]

I checked and the remote machine and the port are accessible in the local machine:

[image]

## Updates

The remote machine is listening on the port:

```
PS C:\Users\User> netstat -aon | Select-String -Pattern ".*9222.*"

  TCP    0.0.0.0:9222           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4296
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9222         127.0.0.1:49152        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9222         127.0.0.1:49153        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9222         127.0.0.1:49154        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9222         127.0.0.1:49155        TIME_WAIT       0
and many more `TIME-WAIT` rows... (not sure what it means)
```

On the local machine, I tried using `chrome://net-export`:

[image]

I can see the attempt of the request in green (#1, so maybe means it is good? idk..). There is a UDP error (#2), but is for port 8888 so I am not sure if it is related.

I have put wireshark in the remote machine, filtering on port 9222:

[image]

It shows activity, but I am not sure what to check there.

I am trying to add chrome debug.

[image]

It says tcp error, but also that devtools is connected on port 9222.

chrome version: 102 (both machines)

How can I debug why it is not connecting?

Comment: Try `chrome://net-export`.

Comment: I tried. I can see activity, but I am not sure what it means. I updated the question with more info

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work. I am not entirely sure what was the issue, but using this script helped:
https://gist.github.com/FreaKzero/1f748482fb0315cde713
(not mine).

Also I think it is important to close any chrome instance before running `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`