# java command line batch file

Tags: java, jar, command-prompt

I have following command line batch file

```
REM test
call java -server -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/codex/props/log4j.xml -Dlog4j.output.dir=C:/logs//codex-logs -jar codex-1.0.jar
```

Question is that is there anyway file can be maintain format having carriage return lines?

something like following for better reading and maintainability???

```
REM test
call java -server -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/codex/props/log4j.xml 
-Dlog4j.output.dir=C:/logs//codex-logs 
-jar codex-1.0.jar
```

Comment: How about defininig the variables and using them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-vista-dos-batch-bat-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Jiri Kremser's answer is correct but if your goal is "better reading and maintainability" , you can use variables too:

```
REM test

set var1=java -server -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
set var2=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/codex/props/log4j.xml
set var3=-Dlog4j.output.dir=C:/logs//codex-logs
set var4=-jar codex-1.0.jar

echo %var1% %var2% %var3% %var4%

call %var1% %var2% %var3% %var4%
```

Comment: @gpa, also you 1+ for my answer would be well appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the character `^` for it

```
REM test
call java -server -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m^ 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/codex/props/log4j.xml^ 
-Dlog4j.output.dir=C:/logs//codex-logs^ 
-jar codex-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe adding simply the backslash '\' at the end of each line will allow you make it behave like one line. Since it escapes the newline character.