# Create an array in batch in multiple lines

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file

I am trying to copy a list of files to a specific directory using a batch file. The first thing I need to do is to create a list of file names. I saw this this post [Create list or arrays in Windows Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch). The following works fine. But I am not happy about the fact that it is in one line. As my list of files gets bigger and bigger, it becomes hard to read.

```
set FILE_LIST=( "file1.txt" "file2.txt" "file3.txt" )
```

And then I noticed this [blog](http://jakash3.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/arrays-in-batch/). It creates an array with multiple lines.

```
set FILE_LIST[0]="file1.txt"
set FILE_LIST[1]="file2.txt"
set FILE_LIST[2]="file3.txt"
```

I am wondering whether there is a way of creating a array as the following:

```
set FILE_LIST=( "file1.txt" 
     "file2.txt" 
     "file3.txt" )
```

so that I can separate the file names into multiple lines, while do not need to worry about the index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the same topic you refer to there is the equivalent of this solution (below "You may also create an array this way"):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for %%a in ("file1.txt"
            "file2.txt"
            "file3.txt"
           ) do (
   set FILE_LIST[!n!]=%%a
   set /A n+=1
)
```

Comment: why did you use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, I've read this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/6680005/4608491 , but I still don't understand why you use it.

Comment: @123iamking: The reason is explained in the [second topic linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) in this question: "You must use `!index!` to store values in array elements when the index is changed inside a FOR or IF: `set elem[!index!]=New value`". The `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command enables the use of `!delayed!` expansion. The `%standard%` expansion does _not_ update the variable value inside an IF or FOR command...

Comment: @123iamking: Your linked answer just answers this question: "Are the two in fact separate commands and can be written on separate lines?". I suggest you to search and read more questions/answers on Delayed Expansion topic, like the answer _[below that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464353/778560)_ that begins this way: "The existing answers don't explain it (sufficiently) IMHO"...

Answer (score 3):

Exactly repeat indents

```
set arr=(^
    "first name"^
    "second name"^
)
```

Check data

```
for %%a in %arr% do (
    echo %%a
)
```

Comment: please consider explaining, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Typed in *.bat file
Setted array of strings and acces to cell of array from for loop iteration
Go to console (cmd), then run *.bat file

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand on Redee's answer because it was better for my purposes than the accepted answer, but it's got a couple typos and it could use an explanation. The `^` character is a line continuation (among other things); it basically says to the interpreter "ignore the following line break character".

So if you want to have a list item every line instead of a gigantic space-delimited list that's impossible to read, the code should look like this:

```
@echo off

set mylist=^
    hello^
    goodbye^
    bonjour^
    hola^
    adios^
    adieu

for %%a in (%mylist%) do echo %%a
```

This outputs the following:

```
hello
goodbye
bonjour
hola
adios
adieu
```

Note that the number of spaces doesn't matter, as long as it's > 1. This will output the same as above:

```
@echo off

set mylist=      ^
  hello          ^
         goodbye ^
 bonjour         ^
       hola      ^
adios            ^
    adieu

for %%a in (%mylist%) do echo %%a
```