# Batch file - Variables in Variables

Tags: batch-file

I've used a for loop to split a string by spaces. I've also used a loop to make each word in its own variable such as var1=this, var2=is, var3=a, var4=test. That looks like "set var!count! = %%A"

That works. I just need to recall it. How do I do that? Logically, I think it would look like this:
%var%count%%

Can someone explain to me how to get that? If I have the 'count' 1, what do I do to get "var1"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch

Comment: I'm getting ECHO is off still... I did the same thing from the link.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way, you'll need to enable the delayed expansion, so first of all place `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, then use exclamation marks to access these variables. Your script should look like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: Here comes your loops to set the variables
echo/!var%count%!
```

Comment: One can do some useful stuff this way, like truncating strings `GOPATH=!WD:%WD:*\src=\src%=!`.

Answer (score 0):

When going through arrays in batch just use `for /l`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
var0 = A
var1 = B
var2 = C
var3 = D
var4 = E

for /l %%a in (0, 1, 4) do (
Echo var%%a = !var%%a!
)
```

#### Output:

```
var0 = A
var1 = B
var2 = C
var3 = D
var4 = E
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need to do that. What you are looking for seems to be an array variable. You could solve the issue with:

```
set variable=this;is;a;test
for %%a in (%variable%) do (echo %%a)
```

For each value you want separate it with a ";"
The output of this code will be:

```
this
is
a
test
```

Comment: (that's a list, not an array). What if you need the third element only?

Comment: It is also called an array, but indeed you are correct in questioning this since the only real way to get a certain value would be to make a for command with for %%i in (variable) do (%var2%+=1&if %var2% equ [number] echo %var2%

Comment: Another way you could do this which I personally like less is to use variablename and then [number] like set var[1]=1 && set var[2]=2 etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print out the contents of var1 outside the for statement use

```
  Echo %var1%
```

To print out the contents of var1 inside the block first , delayed expansion needs to be enabled and instead of enclosing the variable references with percent signs , you use

```
   Echo !var1!
```