# For Loop, List, and TaskKill in Windows Batch Commands

Tags: windows, list, batch-file, for-loop, taskkill

I want to create a list of executables and then create  a for loop to taskkill all of the executables in the list. I used this as reference: [Create list or arrays in Windows Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch) , but I still cannot figure it out.

This is what I tried...

```
set list = A B C D
for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
taskkill /F %%a
)
```

Comment: and what's the issue?

Comment: I am working with Jenkins and it is outputting this to the command line 'for %a in ((null)) do (taskkill %a /F ) '. Instead of taskkilling all the executables in the list.

Comment: If you're using Win7 or above, it might be easier to use [tag:PowerShell] and the `Stop-Process` cmdlet.

Comment: main problem: the spaces with `set`.  Your variabel is named `%list<space>%`. Use `set "list=A B C D"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: setting the list from within the batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:assuming you want to kill the calc.exe, paint.exe and notepad.exe processes
set list=calc paint notepad
for %%a in (!list!) do (
set process=%%a
taskkill /f /im !process!.exe
)
endlocal
```

save the above batch file as method1.bat or include it in your batch file somewhere suitable.

Method 2: have an external list of executables:
make a list of the executables you want to terminate, name it list.txt and make sure the list and the batch file are both in the same folder.
e.g

List.txt:

notepad.exe

paint.exe

calc.exe

your batch file:

```
@echo off
::save this batch file as method2.bat or include in your existing batch file
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%e in (list.txt) do (
set process=%%e
taskkill /f /im !process!
)
endlocal
```

hope that helped!

Comment: What do the lines setlocal enabledelayedexpansion and endlocal do?

Comment: setlocal: Starts localization of environment variables in a batch file. Localization continues until a matching endlocal command is encountered or the end of the batch file is reached. endlocal: ends the setlocal command. enabledelayedexpansion: enabledelayedexpansion : Enables the delayed environment variable expansion until the matching endlocal command is encountered, regardless of the setting prior to the setlocal command. More here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I remember reading somewhere that if I am doing the for loop in the command line then instead of double %'s as shown in "for %%a" you only need one %.  Is this true?