# Batch script Read multi line Argument in Variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I wanted to take list of files to delete from user as a argument. One line per argument.

How can store the list of files separated by new line in a variable.

I am using below command.

```
Set DeletionFiles=${p:DeleteFiles}"

for %%i in (%DeletionFiles%) do (
  echo %%i
)
```

Then i wanted to iterated them on a loop.

`${p:DeleteFiles}` will get replaced by it's value from external app, which will contain list of files separated by new line.I can not change it.

Comment: `${p:DeleteFiles} will get replaced ... which will contain list of files separated by new line.` -- Then it will not work in a bach file! As this wont set a multi line variable, it simply sets the first line and the remaining lines result in errors.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "deletionfiles="

:dloop
SET "deleteme="
SET /p "deleteme=Which file to delete ? "
IF DEFINED deleteme SET "deleteme=%deleteme:"=%"
IF DEFINED deleteme SET "deletionfiles=%deletionfiles%,"%deleteme%""&goto dloop
ECHO delete %deletionfiles:~1%

GOTO :EOF
```

There is no need to use a newline. Your `for` command (or a `del` command) will operate perfectly happily on a comma-(or space-)separated list.

Note that there are certain characters that batch uses for special purposes and batch string-processing may not process them in the expected manner. These characters include `%` `^` and `&`.

Comment: I am getting files name from external app. i can not change the input structure. It will contain new line string

Answer (score 0):

> ${p:DeleteFiles} will get replaced by it's value from external app,
>   which will contain list of files separated by new line.I can not
>   change it.

After the replacement the batch file looks like:

```
Set DeletionFiles=file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
"
```

This isn't a valid batch file anymore.
Furthermore it's a bad idea to modify the batch file itself, as this works only once.

You could place the `${p:DeleteFiles}` into another file, like `input.txt`.

Your batch would look like

```
echo ${p:DeleteFiles} > input.txt

<external program for replacing the DeleteFiles> input.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do (
  echo File: %%A
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your external program will generate a list of files.  You then want to store this multi-line list to a variable.  What do you want to do with the variable once you have it?  I assume you want to delete the files, but your question isn't clear on that point, so I'll try to over-answer to cover it.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('{command that generates your list}') do (
    echo Doing stuff to %%a...
    echo %%a>>listOfFilesToDelete.txt
    set var=%%a
    if "%var:~0,7%"="DoNotDelete" copy "%%a" \someArchiveFolder\
    del "%%a"
)
```

This will read each line in your generated list as variable `%%a`.   It will then `do` whatever command(s) you specify.  This way, you can run a command on each of the files in the list. In the above code it's

1. Printing each line to the console embedded in some text
2. Outputting it to a file
3. Checking the first 7 characters of the line against a specified string and then copying it to a folder if it matches
4. And then deleting it

If you still need to reference each line from your generated list, you can even setup an array-like structure.  (See [Create list or arrays in Windows Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch/17606350#17606350))

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:: Capture lines in an 'array'
set /a i=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b') do (
    set /a i+=1
    set var!i!=%%a
)

:: Loop through the 'array'
for /L %%a in (1,1,%i%) do (
   echo Do more stuff with !var%%a!
)
```

Just like above, this will read each line in your generated list as variable `%%a`.  It will then set a variable `var!i!` equal to the value of the current line.  You can then reference each line as `var1`, `var2`, and so on, or, as the second section shows, you can loop through them all using `for /L`.  You'll need to get a grasp on working with delayed expansion variables, though.