# Concatenate a list of paths to a variable - to pass to "java -classpath ..." in CMD batch script

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7

I am trying to port [a simple shell script](https://github.com/afarber/jetty-newbie/blob/master/WebsocketHandler/start_emb_jetty_mac.sh) starting a Java program to a CMD batch script for Windows:

```
@echo on

set REPO="C:\Users\user1\.m2\repository"
set VERSION=9.3.9.v20160517

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe" -classpath C:\Users\user1\slova\WebSockets\target\classes;%REPO%\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-server\%VERSION%\websocket-server-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-common\%VERSION%\websocket-common-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\%VERSION%\jetty-io-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-client\%VERSION%\websocket-client-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlet\%VERSION%\jetty-servlet-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-security\%VERSION%\jetty-security-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-server\%VERSION%\jetty-server-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\%VERSION%\jetty-http-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-servlet\%VERSION%\websocket-servlet-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-api\%VERSION%\websocket-api-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util-ajax\%VERSION%\jetty-util-ajax-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\%VERSION%\jetty-util-%VERSION%.jar;%REPO%\org\postgresql\postgresql\9.4.1208.jre7\postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar de.afarber.websockets.MyHandler
```

As you can see (if you scroll the above code to the right) there is a longer list of file paths following the `java -classpath` string.

Is it please possible to list the paths each on a separate line - and then concatenate that list by the means of CMD shell to a variable (adding semicolon `;` inbetween)?

That way I could better maintain my batch file (easier to edit in editor) and would finally just call `java -classpath %CPATHS% de.afarber.websockets.MyHandler`

**UPDATE:**

If all JAR-files would be located in the same dir, I could have used [the new Java 8 wildcard syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) `java -classpath "\that\dir\*" de.afarber.websockets.MyHandler` - but that wasn't the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable in this form:

```
set MYCLASSPATH=C:\Users\user1\slova\WebSockets\target\classes
set MYCLASSPATH=%MYCLASSPATH%;%REPO%\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
...

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe" -classpath %MYCLASSPATH% ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work! But isn't there some array variable in CMD? Or maybe a variable holding several lines (like HERE-assignment in Unix shell and PHP/Perl scripts)? To improve the readability

Comment: @AlexanderFarber see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch

Comment: Your trick with appending paths to the same variable `MYCLASSPATH` is actually so simple and good, that I could use it in my Unix shell script as well :-)

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks. Have changed it

Comment: `set "MYCLASSPATH=C:\Users\user1\slova\WebSockets\target\classes;"` contains trailing `;` semicolon. Then after `set MYCLASSPATH=%MYCLASSPATH%;%REPO%\…`, the `MYCLASSPATH` variable would contain **doubled**  `;;` semicolon. (I don't know why my previous comment disappeared?)