# windows batch script for loop variable expansion not working

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

I am following this tutorial on windows script arrays and for loops. The examples are not working, tested on both windows 7 and 10.

[Batch script tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_arrays.htm/%22Batch%20script%20tutorial%22u)

When I run the following for loop:

```
:: @echo off 
set list = 1 2 3 4 
(for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
    echo %%a 
))
```

I get the following output:

```
set list = 1 2 3 4
(for %a in ((null)) do (echo %a  ) )
```

The content of the list varialble is not printed in the for loop. I was expecting to get

```
1
2
3
4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your variable was named `list<space>`. Change `%list%` to `%list %`

Comment: even better: get rid of the spaces around the `=`. They become part of the varaible name repectively the value.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it must be something simple. It is also wrong in the tutorial examples.

Comment: Yes, it is. Check out the batch page on the Documentation site, instead.

Answer (score 2):

For info on using basic batch commands like SET, see [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) great info source. In your case, as was commented above, the expanded variable name %list % must include space if present in its definition. If that space is not required in the variable definition, just remove it in the SET statement.

Spaces between array variable *values* list don't represent any problem, and can be quite handy in many example applications, in particular FOR loops, as they allow tokens use for finding the right values. This example works:

```
@echo off 
set "list= 1 2 3 4"
for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
    echo %%a 
)
```

For learning use of arrays in batch scripts, read *Aacini*'s answers:

- [Create list or arrays in Windows Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch)
- [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch)
  script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)
- [Arrays, structures and linked lists in Batch files](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3244)

Using "array" terminology in batches is debated by some experts. See for example *dbenham*'s answer in [DIR output into BAT array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544646/dir-output-into-bat-array)

Comment: You fixed the problem in the code without explaining what the problem was, or how you fixed it. The rest of your answer obscures the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Added verbal explanation, though it was obvious from the script, which in many instances is the best and sufficient explanation "by example". Sorry, if I missed any of your contributions to the Array subject, pls add relevant links here or in the answer. :)

Comment: @Pohl7534 If the script works for you, consider upvoting AND accepting any answer in this thread by clicking "Arrow Up" and "Select" signs to the left of the answer. :)