# How can i write a for loop in bat and execute a command on each iteration

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to accomplish the following in a bat script

I want to create an array, in which the elements are separated by space, for instance:

```
array = host1 host2 host3
```

And run a `for` loop on that array where each element is passed as a parameter to a command for instance: `psexec //host1 cmd` likewise all the server names should be passed as an argument.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your data is not an _array_, but a _list_. Further details at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch/17606350#17606350)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it with a list like below:

```
@echo off 
set list=host1 host2 host3
(for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
   ;dosomething with %%a;
))
```

Please be aware when setting the list and do not put any spaces before and after `=`

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in (%array%) do echo %%a
```

for use directly on commandline, replace every `%%a` with `%a`.

Comment: In the place of echo can i write psexec  command and echo it to a txt file

Comment: of course - why not? You can do with `%%a` whatever you want.