# Batch script loop through specific type of files in current directory and get the latest created and next latestcreated files and so on

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, windows-7-x64, datecreated

I have following script to loop through specific type of files and get information about `date` and `time` of their creation:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :getCreationInfo
cmd /k

:getCreationInfo
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4,5* delims= " %%a in ('dir /a:-d /o:d /t:c *.bak') do (
    if "%%~c" NEQ "bytes" (
        echo(
        @echo File Name: %%~d
        @echo Absolute Path: %%~fd
        @echo Creation Date: %%~a
        @echo Creation Time: %%~b
        echo(
    )
)
```

But how do I order this list in descending, like latest created file first and then the next created file and then the next and store these in an array ?

I am stuck in this ordering thing, hoping anyone to help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a hyphen in the order clause as in /o:-d instead of /o:d.  This worked for me in the command prompt screen.

Try this link for putting the results in an array:  [Create list or arrays in Windows Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch)

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :getCreationInfo
cmd /k

:getCreationInfo
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4,5* delims= " %%a in ('dir /a:-d /o:-d /t:c *.bak') do (
    if "%%~c" NEQ "bytes" (
        echo(
        @echo File Name: %%~d
        @echo Absolute Path: %%~fd
        @echo Creation Date: %%~a
        @echo Creation Time: %%~b
        echo(
    )
)
```

Comment: Wow man, you're a life saver, can these file paths be stored in an array in same order ?

Comment: Try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch

Comment: Please add the reference link in your answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @Vicky Dev  Done, Thanks!