# How can I address element i+1 in a FOR loop in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have an array in a batch file where I would like to get in each iteration the `i` element and `i+1` (called in my batch `serialNumberSection`), starting from the second position of the input. So far, I have been able to get the `i` elements but I cannot do the same with the `i+1` and I don't understand why.

What am I doing wrong?

```
input array = [0x33333 0xAA 0x33323130 0xBB 0x37363534 0xCC
0x42413938 0xDD 0x46454443]
```

My code

```
set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
    set /A argCount+=1
    set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)
echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%

set serialNumberSection=2
for /L %%i in (2,2,%argCount%) do (
    echo %%i- "!argVec[%%i]!"
    set /A serialNumberSection+=1
    echo %%serialNumberSection !argVec[%%serialNumberSection]!
)
```

My output

```
Number of processed arguments: 9
2- "0xAA"
%serialNumberSection <=Expected: 0x33323130
4- "0xBB"
%serialNumberSection <=Expected: 0x37363534 
6- "0xCC"
%serialNumberSection <=Expected: 0x42413938 
8- "0xDD"
%serialNumberSection <=Expected: 0x46454443
```

Comment: `%%serialNumberSection` is your issue, a `%variable%` uses slightly different batch file syntax to the `%%metavariable`. Also as its value is being updated inside the loop it too would need some form of expansion delay.

Comment: Instead of `echo %%serialNumberSection !argVec[%%serialNumberSection]!`, use either `call echo !serialNumberSection! %%argVec[!serialNumberSection!]%%` or `for %%j in (!serialNumberSection!) do echo %%j !argVec[%%j]!`...

Comment: This type of management is described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: @Aacini, I already referred to this post in my answer below... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the line:

```cmd
echo %%serialNumberSection !argVec[%%serialNumberSection]!
```

use either:

```cmd
call echo !serialNumberSection! %%argVec[!serialNumberSection!]%%
```

or:

```cmd
for %%j in (!serialNumberSection!) do echo %%j !argVec[%%j]!
```

`%%serialNumberSection` is wrong syntax, because the prefix `%%` is only valid for `for` variable references (like your `%%i`), but `serialNumberSection` is a normal environment variable.

`%serialNumberSection%` does not work, because you are updating the variable inside the loop.

`!serialNumberSection!` works, but not to expand your array elements, because delayed expansion cannot be nested (so `!argVec[!serialNumberSection!]!` fails as it tries to expand variables `argVec[` and `]`, and `serialNumberSection` is considered as a literal string), hence you need to work around that.

Reference also this articles:

- [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990)
- [Create list or arrays in Windows Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17606350)

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl, one more question if I would like to use those values as input to a binary, something like `my.exe !argVec[%%i]!  call echo !serialNumberSection! %%argVec[!serialNumberSection!]%%` should I use the `call echo` or the `for %%j ...` to address the second parameter?

Comment: I would use this (inside your `for /L %%i` loop): `for %%j in (!serialNumberSection!) do my.exe !argVec[%%i]! !argVec[%%j]!` (because it is more obvious and it may be faster than `call`; if you want to use `call`, try this: `call my.exe !argVec[%%i]! %%argVec[!serialNumberSection!]%%`)