# I Want to get many Input from the user using for loop in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, for-loop

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,10) DO (
SET /P INPUT%%A= ENTER THE FIRST INPUT :
ECHO %INPUT%%A% )
```

:: Here is my problem i dont know how to get a value in variable INPUT%%A

Comment: You're looking for [how to create an array in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-list-or-arrays-in-windows-batch). Specifically, look at Aacini's answer.

Comment: To `Echo` it in the loop, _(which seems absolutely unnecessary in this case)_, you'll need either a pseudo `Call`: `CALL ECHO %%INPUT%%A%%`, or to have previously enabled delayed expansion: `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, before using `ECHO !INPUT%%A!`. You should also change the wording, the use of `FIRST` would only be appropriate once!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `delayedexpansion`. From cmd console run `setlocal /?` for help on it. As an example, if you want to set a standard variable name of `!output!`, but change the content of it to include the number of the loop counter:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
  if %%i equ 1 set handle=st
  if %%i equ 2 set handle=nd
  if %%i equ 3 set handle=rd
  if %%i geq 4 (if %%i lss 11 set handle=th)
  set /p "input=What is your %%I!handle! input? :"
  set input=!input!%%i
  echo !input!
)
```

You also do not want to echo 1st each time you call the input, the 2nd is not 1st, so see the if statements examples.