# Python pakage Offline Installation

Tags: python, pip, package

I have below code, which am using for package installation wondering is there a better way to optimize it as there is duplication of commands for my offline installation process. I have tried various suggestions but none of them worked and this simple method worked. But would like to optimize it bit better.

```
@echo off
cls
REM Check if Python is installed 
Set PATH "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib"
echo checking python verion
Python --version
REM Install PyInstaller and its dependencies using pip
echo Copying Python packages from source to "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib location"
copy c:\python_modules\*.whl "c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib"
echo Packages coppied successfully....Proceeding to Install
REM SET PATH "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib"
cd "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib"
pip install --disable-pip-version-check altgraph-0.17.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Echo ****Installing next Package****
pip install --disable-pip-version-check Cython-0.29.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Echo ****Installing next Package ****
pip install --disable-pip-version-check packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl
Echo ****Installing next Package ****
pip install --disable-pip-version-check pefile-2023.2.7-py3-none-any.whl
Echo ****Installing next Package ****
pip install --disable-pip-version-check pyinstaller_hooks_contrib-2023.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Echo ****Installing next Package ****
pip install --disable-pip-version-check pywin32_ctypes-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
Echo ****Installing next Package ****
pip install --disable-pip-version-check setuptools-69.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Echo ****Installing next Package ****
Pip install --disable-pip-version-check wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl
Echo ****Installing next Package ****
pip install --disable-pip-version-check pyinstaller-6.2.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl
REM pip install pyinstaller 
REM Check the installation 
Echo Checking packages instllation 
pip list --disable-pip-version-check
REM Uninstalling Python packages 
Echo Uninstalling Python packages 
pip uninstall -y altgraph
pip uninstall -y cython
pip uninstall -y packaging
pip uninstall -y pefile
pip uninstall -y pyinstaller_hooks_contrib
pip uninstall -y pywin32_ctypes
pip uninstall -y setuptools
pip uninstall -y wheel
pip uninstall -y pyinstaller

cd C:\python_modules\
```

the above code works but looking to have optimized version
also want to know which dependencies are required if not there for the packages

Comment: If you already have all the `.whl` files in a directory (the ***wheelhouse***), then I guess something like this could work: `pip install --no-index --no-deps path/to/wheelhouse/*.whl` -- Read also: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/repeatable-installs/#using-a-wheelhouse-aka-installation-bundles

Comment: this is a windows environment and  tried this option didn't work. i shall give it another go. however I also would like to know if any of the package has any dependencies or not.

Comment: on Linux you could use `*.whl` and `bash` would replace it with all files with extension `.whl`. On Windows probably you would need to use `for`-loop in `batch` to get files which match `*.whl`

Comment: see [windows - Iterate all files in a directory using a 'for' loop - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop). It suggets `for /r %i in (*) do pip ... %i`  for all files in folder but for `*.whl` you would try `for /r %i in (*.whl) do pip ... %i`

Comment: see [Create a list or an array and print each item in Windows Batch - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605767/create-a-list-or-an-array-and-print-each-item-in-windows-batch) to create list with names to use it with `uninstall`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! is there any way it can be made this code better?