# Why does this .BAT line split with caret fail?

Tags: windows-7, cmd

Why does this .BAT line split with caret fail?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because not only does `^` continue the line by ignoring the linefeed, it also escapes the first character of the next line. So the `>` is treated as a literal instead of as redirection.

You can get the exact same error result using:

```
type C:\temp.txt ^> C:\temp2.txt
```

You can fix the multiline version by putting a space before the redirection

```
type C:\temp.txt ^
 > C:\temp2.txt
```

The rules are actually a bit more complex than what I have described. See [jeb's explanation of how caret works at end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455750/1012053)

Comment: Thanks. "You can fix the multiline version by putting a space before the redirection" Since that space then appears, I'd remove the space before the ^. It there an escaped character that's safe to always use on the start of the next line as a sacrifice, consumed?

Comment: @ChrisJJ - I don't understand what you mean by "that space then appears". You can put as many spaces before the `>` as you want and it will not affect the output. If your were executing ECHO, then I could understand the concern, but this is a TYPE statement.

Comment: I find spaces before the > do affect the output e.g. http://i.imgur.com/ETrF4Qy.png

Comment: @ChrisJJ - That affects the appearance of the parsed line when ECHO is ON. But it does not affect the output of TYPE that is redirected to your file.

Comment: Agreed. (more characters)