# What is the convention for line wrapping in command-line instructions?

Tags: command-line, documentation

I need to document some very long command line instructions. What convention should I use to indicate that the line is not broken?

For example, for the command:

```
fab --fabfile=create_virtualenv.py --hosts=<user@remote> create_virtualenv:base=<base_folder>,name=<ve_name>,requirements=<requirements_file>,packages=<package_folder>
```

I was thinking:

```
fab --fabfile=create_virtualenv.py --hosts=<user@remote> \\
create_virtualenv:base=<base_folder>,name=<ve_name>,\\
requirements=<requirements_file>,packages=<package_folder>
```

but that's just me making something up based on a half-forgotten example, and I can see potential for ambiguities regarding whitespace and punctuation.

A referenced standard would be best, or consistent, well-regarded implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, I would use the same character that CMD.EXE uses for line continuation - the caret `^`.

```
fab --fabfile=create_virtualenv.py --hosts=<user@remote> ^
create_virtualenv:base=<base_folder>,name=<ve_name>,^
requirements=<requirements_file>,packages=<package_folder>
```

See [Long commands split over multiple lines in Windows Vista batch (.bat) file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69068/1012053) for more info. Be sure to read the first three answers, as they each have useful information.

On 'nix, I would use a single `\` for the same reason. A double `\\` would imply a backslash literal, so that is not good. But a single `\` at the end implies line continuation.

```
fab --fabfile=create_virtualenv.py --hosts=<user@remote> \
create_virtualenv:base=<base_folder>,name=<ve_name>,\
requirements=<requirements_file>,packages=<package_folder>
```