# Breaking FINDSTR Command into Multiple Lines in a Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

My FINDSTR command is very lengthy and I want to break it into multiple lines in my batch file. Here is the command:

```
type file.txt | findstr /v "string1" | findstr /v "string2" | findstr /v "string3" | findstr /v "string4" > newfile.txt
```

Is this possible? Ideally, I'd like each sequence (divided by the pipe characters) to be on its own line.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `^` character:

```
type file.txt ^
    | findstr /v "string1" ^
    | findstr /v "string2" ^
    | findstr /v "string3" ^
    | findstr /v "string4" > newfile.txt
```

This is a normal way of splitting command into several lines in `cmd`.

See also: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-vista-dos-batch-bat-file).

Comment: When I run the batch file in CMD, this is what it says:

`' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: you are right, there should be no spaces before the command. I edited the answer, now splitting lines before `|` character. Checked that it works.