# Activate virtualenv and run .py script from .bat

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, virtualenv

I'd like to use Windows Task Scheduler to run a python script within a virtual environment. I'd like the Scheduler to run a .bat file that will

1. activate the virtualenv
2. run the script

These steps work together from the command line, and they work individually in a .bat, but I can't seem to get them to work together from the .bat. It seems the virtualenv is not fully activated when I try to execute the python script and confused as to why.

My .bat looks like this:

```
call workon venv
cd path/to/Python/proj
python -m script.py
```

I've tried adding timeouts immediately after the call to `workon` and tried moving the `workon` to seperate .bat called from my first file, but the other lines still execute before the virtualenv is activated. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this answer might be similar and helpful [A python script that activates the virtualenv and then runs another python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30927921/1248974)

Comment: I saw that thread earlier but wasn't aware of the importance of chaining the statements together with the `&` operator as @Gerhard pointed out below. Including the `&` operator resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use an ampersand `&` operator in a oneliner batch file.

```
call workon venv & cd path/to/Python/proj & python -m script.py
```

It will run each command after the other.

You can also double up the ampersand to make it a conditional operator. `&&`:

```
call workon venv && cd path/to/Python/proj && python -m script.py
```

Here  the command will only run, if the previous command completed successfully, in other words `ERRORLEVEL = 0`

Comment: This one works also to activate environment and start streamlit app

Answer (score 72):

You do not need to activate the virtual environment while running in .bat. All you need to do is to run the python.exe file in your virtual environment.

In Windows Task Scheduler you can specify the path in which the command prompt will open. So when adding the action, use path to your python in the field `Program/script`, the name of the file to be run in `Add arguments` field, and the path to your `file.py` in `Start in` field.

[image: windows task scheduler example]

P.S if you are reading or writing files in your python file, note that your path will be relative to the one you specify in your `start in`  field in the Action window

Comment: The wisdom I was searching for. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Just type

`call .\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

in the .bat file and any command afterwards will see the venv activated

for the record `call` in a cmd pauses the execution of the current script, executes the called one and then resumes.

Answer (score 4):

your os must be linux or mac because your path is "path/to/Python/proj"

in window, it is "path\to\Python\proj"

in my window machine, scripts below works

```
call "venv\scripts\activate"
cd ur_path
py script.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't have to activate virtual environment. In the batch file, start the python script by using your virtual environment's python path. i.e

```
 start C:\mypythonproject\Scripts\python C:\mypythonproject\mycode.py
```

And in the task scheduler, just schedule your batch file as a regular file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to make a shortcut of the batch file and then change the "Start in" field.
After that remember to use the full paths in your batch file since it will be running from a difference location.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Create .bat file

write virtual environment activate script location and python file location as below use '&' operator to run two commands.

as below:

```
"E:\Call Allocation Engine\Development\development_env\Scripts\"activate & python run.py
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Gkh.png

finally place this file in desired folder and run using cmd.

```
E:\Call Allocation Engine\Development\Optimisation\Scheduling>file_name.bat
```

this script will activate virtual environment and run your python code in that environment.

Answer (score -3):

Edit `activate.bat` and place this line at the bottom:

```
python yourscript.py
```

Schedule the `activate.bat` itself and it will automatically run your script after the virtual environment activated.