# How to open a python file in background with a virtual environment activated on PC startup?

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, startup, python-venv, pythonw

I have a python file that needs a virtual environment to be activated in order to be run, and I want this file to be run whenever I start my PC. Problem is a terminal window opens even though I'm using pythonw. It is just a blank terminal window.

So here is what I did,
I created a bat file that looks like this
`d:\folder\venv\Scripts\pythonw.exe d:\folder\thefile.py`
this does not fully work because even though it does not open a terminal window for the python file it does open a blank terminal window that I have to close manually. I want to get rid of this.
Finally I thought I can put the bat file here
`C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: You don't want, or need, a batch file. Create a shortcut and place it in your `Startup` directory instead. A batch file runs in `cmd.exe`, hence why the window is opening. BTW, had you used ```@start d:\folder\venv\Scripts\pythonw.exe d:\folder\thefile.py``` you wouldn't have had to close the `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: @Compo shortcut for what exactly? the python file? how will I activate the virtual environment if I directly add the shortcut to the python file?
Also, using start works thank you

Comment: How are you activating it now? You can't be doing it with the batch file, because I was very careful to read your question, which stated, "I created a bat file that looks like this d:\folder\venv\Scripts\pythonw.exe d:\folder\thefile.py".

Comment: actually, with a batch file you don't need to activate the virtual environment. Just running the python.exe in the virtual environment directory is enough.
d:\folder\venv\Scripts\pythonw.exe  [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425520/activate-virtualenv-and-run-py-script-from-bat)

Comment: You asked how, not me! "how will I activate the virtual environment if I directly add the shortcut to the python file?"

Comment: you asked me to use a shortcut instead of a batch file. I know how it is done with a batch file, apart from the small issue I had, which you helped me with so thank you for that, but I don't know how to use a shortcut to achieve the same, which is why I asked

Comment: Did you try, Target: `pythonw.exe ..\..\thefile.py` Start in: `D:\folder\venv\Scripts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue, and I put a Python script in `shell:startup` with .pyw but it still opened a terminal.
here are the essential tips:

1. Ensure that `pythonw.exe` was used as your interpreter.
2. start your bat file with `@echo off`
   your bat file should be like this:

```
@echo off
start /B pythonw.exe path_to_your_script.py
exit
```

This command will automatically open a blank terminal and close it within a second.

another way is instead of directly placing the .pyw file in the startup folder, you can create a shortcut to the script:

- Navigate to your script.
- Right-click and choose "Create shortcut".
- Place this shortcut in your startup folder.