# Cannot activate venv inside Jenkinsfile on Windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline file which shall be executed on a Windows machine.
The venv is created correctly but cannot be activated.
The stage just stops there without an error.
Any thoughts on this?

```
pipeline {  
    environment{
        PYTHON_VERSION = 3.9
        VENV_DIR = 'venv39'
        DEV_REQUIREMENTS = 'requirements_dev.txt'
    }


    stages {

        stage('Creating venv') {
            steps {
                bat '''
                echo Set up venv
                py -%PYTHON_VERSION% -m venv ./%VENV_DIR%
                echo activate venv
                .\\%VENV_DIR%\\Scripts\\activate.bat
                echo installing requirements
                pip install -r %DEV_REQUIREMENTS%
                '''
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use call to activate the venv

```
call .\\%VENV_DIR%\\Scripts\\activate.bat
```

see also
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76501630/5295445